# How to alter the InvoiceID/ContributionID count

Tags: civicontribute, wordpress, accounting, invoice

I'm wondering if is possible to alter the current Contribution_ID start count.

The invoice prefix is set to "INV" so when viewing a contribution I can see the invoice ID like INV76, I guess the ID comes from the contribution_id which matches with invoice_id in any single contribution. I would like to alter the current count so the next contribution_id starts with for example 4076.

Resuming, my target is to change the count of the invoice_id so it matches with our current invoices count (right now is about 4356) as we would like to use this fantastic CiviCRM feature.

Any help is appreciated.

CiviCRM 4.6.X Wordpress 4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the auto-increment number:

```
ALTER TABLE civicrm_contribution AUTO_INCREMENT = 4356;
```

Note that this is very dangerous if you set the number backward rather than forward.

Comment: Great! Thanks Jon, I wasn't sure if that was the way to go.